# What will the laptop do if I close the lid when plugged in then unplug it after I've closed the lid?

Tags: windows-vista, power-management, sleep, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

If my laptop is set to "do nothing when I close the lid when plugged in" and "hibernate when I close the lid when on battery, what will the laptop do if I close the lid when plugged in then unplug it after I've closed the lid?

(I'm using 32-bit Windows Vista home premium service pack 2, acer aspire 4937G laptop )

Comment: whoahh. I don't know how I've never thought of this before. Excellent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on your Power Management settings. Since you've set to "Do Nothing" when plugged in and when laptop lid is closed - when you close the lid - since the laptop is still plugged it, it will follow the rule and it will still remain on.

Once the the plug is pulled - it will follow the power management settings for unplugged - rightaway nothing will happen, once the battery starts draining & once the thresholds for various events ( Read: If idle for x time do y) are met, those particular actions will take place.

If these rules are set as do nothing even during battery mode, then at the power management rules for low battery mode & critical battery mode will take place.

Comment: how do i set `rules for low battery mode & critical battery mode` ? i'm using acer aspire 4937G btw

Comment: Go to `Control Panel` -> `Hardware & Sound` -> `Power Options`. See which plan is active ( there will be a radiobox selected to it) and click on `Change plan settings`

Comment: i did select change plan settings but of those options it doesn't have a way for us to indicate rules for low battery and critical battery mode: http://i.imgur.com/Dw2QD.jpg

Comment: ok so basically we can't indicate rules for `low battery` but we can indicate rules for `not used in a while`?

Comment: @Pacerier - seems the Acer Power Management thingy has taken over Windows' plans settings. This is how it looks on my laptop http://i.imgur.com/X41lW.png. The advanced settings option has more granular options http://i.imgur.com/HjUxh.png

Answer (score 3):

I don't think anything will happen.  The lid has already been closed, so you've already triggered the ACPI event for that (in this case, it didn't do anything).  Pulling the plug would trigger that event, but I don't think it would re-trigger the lid closure event.  Just try it to be certain.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try it? My guess is nothing since it probably takes the actual act of closing the lid to trigger the hibernation.

Comment: You also don't mention which version of Windows you are running. It may matter.

Comment: i've edited the question with that info